# Why is PyQt5 showing me my first file dialog but not my second one?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, dialog, pyqt5, widget

I am trying to make a basic front-end gui for a python project using PyQt5. Specifically, I would  like to start with two things. First, I would like to prompt the user to select an input data file. Then, I would like to prompt the user to select a directory into which files can be saved.

A working example of the code can be found below. **My question is why the user only receives one prompt when there are two prompt in the code for the user (first for the input file, then for the save directory).** The code does not throw an error; commenting out the input file routine (`self.select_save_directory()` in the `__init__` method of `Interface`) will allow for the save directory routine to run.

First, all of the imports.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets # QtGui, QtCore
```

Then, the widget that prompts the user to select an input .csv file.

```
class FileSelectionWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click here and select the data file you want to read")
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        self._fpath = None

    @property
    def fpath(self):
        return self._fpath

    def on_clicked(self):
        dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(
            self,
            "Select input file",
            "path",
            "*.csv",
            supportedSchemes=["file"],
            options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        fpath = dialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open file', '/home')[0]
        self._fpath = fpath
        self.close()
        print(self.fpath) # verify
```

Then, the widget that prompts the user to select a save directory.

```
class DirectorySelectionWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    """
    This class allows the user to select the directory
    to save files into via gui.
    """

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click here and select the directory \nin which you would like to save files")
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        self._savedir = None

    @property
    def savedir(self):
        return self._savedir

    def on_clicked(self):
        dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog()
        savedir = dialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select directory")
        self._savedir = savedir
        self.close()
        print(self.savedir) # verify
```

I plan to add my existing back-end.

```
class BackEnd():

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    # data processing functions
```

Finally, the interface that inherits methods from the back-end and can call/instantiate the UI methods above.

```
class Interface(BackEnd):

    def __init__(self):
        """

        """
        super().__init__()
        self.select_data_file()
        self.select_save_directory()
        ... # more back-end things

    def select_data_file(self):
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        file_selection_widget = FileSelectionWidget()
        file_selection_widget.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def select_save_directory(self):
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        directory_selection_widget = DirectorySelectionWidget()
        directory_selection_widget.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    interface = Interface()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [`sys.exit([arg])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit):
> Exit from Python.

This has nothing to do with PyQt. The problem is that both `select_data_file` and `select_save_directory` end with `sys.exit`, causing your program to *immediately* quit, no matter what functions are called afterwards.

Besides that, if you're going to reuse the dialogs (or show something else within the life span of the program), it's usually better to avoid recreation of a QApplication.

What you can do is to start a *single* QApplication in your `main`, then change your classes to QDialog instead of QWidget and show them using `exec_()` instead of `show()`. This allows keeping the same "blocking" effect you have right now (with `app.exec_()`) that will be cleared as soon as the dialog is closed, and then you can show other windows whenever you feel it necessary.

Do note that to prevent further program quitting, you should use [`setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop) and then manually call `QApplication.quit()` when you want to actually quit.

Finally, be aware that both `getOpenFileName` and `getExistingDirectory` are *static* methods of QFileDialog. They return a *new* pre-constructed file dialog instance, so creating an instance before that is pointless.
You need to add the arguments to the static function itself.

```
   def on_clicked(self):
        fpath, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            None, 'Select input file', '/home', '*.csv', 
            options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        if fpath:
            self._fpath = fpath
            self.close()
```

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote, but thanks. The part about `sys.exit` and using only one `QApplication` makes sense.  Regarding your last paragraph, what instance are you referring to when you say "creating an instance before that is pointless"?

Comment: In the first line of `on_clicked` you are creating a new instance (`dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(...)`). That instance will never be used, since using `getOpenFileName` creates a completely new instance. See my edit, which includes the full function and gets rid of that part, since it's unnecessary